# Magento 2 Export Processor does not seem to finish

Tags: magento2

Platform: Magento2.

How a stupid am i! I used the command to process export product manually following this tut: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033513352-Exported-products-csv-file-does-not-appear.

However, the command

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

does not finish for along.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z4YQ.jpg

To the moment, it has run about 1h and it is still alive. Can I simply do kill it by CRTL + c? It will affected to others or our site?

Kindly give me some advice on this issue!

Comment: if you have kill it by CRTL + c then not effect on your site and others if stopped the command. also, you can check your export successfully done if you can check

Comment: Hi @BhaveshGodhani, Until now, it is still alive. I thought there is no way to choose. Thank you for support, i'm going to do that and i will double check, if any issues, i will back it on comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,You can kill it by CRTL + c and also you can stop this proccess too throgh below command. this will not affect on site.

```
ps ufx | grep cron
```

The output should resemble output shown below:

```
root 12080 0.0 0.0 117328 460 ? Ss Mar25 5:23 crond
username 26529 0.0 0.0 103244 848 pts/0 S+ 22:33 0:00 \_ grep cron
username 6876 5.0 0.3 646760 88476 ? S 15:42 20:50 /usr/bin/php /chroot/home/username/domainname.com/html/cron:run index
```

Kill it

```
kill -9 6876
```

6876 should your proccess id.

Comment: Thank your for your explanation. I did. Thought, I've been worrying about this too much.